# Solr as "Standalone binary in Desktop Client" without server

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I am using Lucene for creating small searching utility. I need to index files/DB data & search over the index. Lucene has few features that I am looking at (index txt files, portable index). I need some more features like indexing different types of file, index DB, sync/merge index & weight/rating system for search index data.

- Is it possible to use SOLRJ API (binaries only) for standalone client utility development (without server running)? I find it difficult to start EmbeddedSolrServer. Any example on *standalone* or *EmbeddedSolrServer* would be much appreciated.
- Is it possible to use Lucene API & SolrJ API in parallel to address limitations of lucene?

Comment: SOLR is a webservice and its not “Standalone binary in Desktop Client”
SOLR is only available in two modes
1. Standalone and
2. Cloud mode .
Standalone mode will have one copy of your data and serve from the single node while the cloud is on the cluster mode.
SOLRJ is an Java API to access the SOLR server.

Answer (score 1):

Solr itself (even if you aren't using SolrJ) offers a very easy way to talk to it directly using a REST interface. It's usable as a 'microservice'. I'm about to build a desktop search utility, and all it's going to consist of is the ability to submit a search request (REST call, via simple URL call), and then get the resulting found files in a list so that the user can click them to edit. Basically the point of my post is you DO NOT need to "embed" Solr into your application to use it. Just let it be the service running on the machine just like a MongoDB instance or a DB instance or many other things are that run in separate processes. Leave it external, and just make calls to it, even if you are using it only on a single machine like the desktop search tool i'm about to write.

Answer (score 0):

SolrJ is made for talking to Solr. That can be an EmbeddedSolr, or a separate instance. If you're not using Solr, SolrJ won't do anything for you. You're going to have to get an EmbeddedSolr instance running in that case.

If you're going to use SolrJ and Solr, I'd avoid doing anything directly through Lucene if possible. Pick one - either use Lucene directly, or use it through Solr. Both approaches will work, but the setup task will be different.

Solr uses Tika for document indexing, so if you're implementing Lucene directly, you want to link against Tika and use it yourself just as Solr does.

Weight/rating is supported in the same manner both places (Solr uses Lucene for this and Lucene's own DefaultSimilarity by default).